# Why is AC coupling needed between PHY and Fiber transceiver?

Tags: phy

I'm using the DP83620 with the AFBR-5803 Avago transceiver.  This question is not specific to these parts, but I'm including them for the sake of clarity.  The datasheets for both devices indicates that they are PECL compatible.  The reference schematic in the DP83620 datasheet (page 35) includes AC coupling for the TD+/- pair.

If the two devices work with the same logic levels, why is AC coupling needed?  Why wouldn't it be necessary to include AC coupling for the RD+/- pair? (at least according to TI's datasheet?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

"PECL compatible" doesn't mean the part actually has a PECL topology in the output driver circuit, it just means it can be used with PECL parts.

In fact Fig 9 of the DP83620 [datasheet](http://datasheet.octopart.com/DP83620SQE/NOPB-Texas-Instruments-datasheet-10844199.pdf) strongly implies the DP83620 outputs are **not** PECL because true PECL would require a pull-down resistor on the output in order to function at all.

Since the DP83620 datasheet never as far as I can tell gives an equivalent circuit for the outputs, you can't really do much other than follow the recommended application circuit in Fig. 9.

Comment: I'm going to follow their guidelines anyways, but wanted to have a better understanding.  That's a good point about not being true PECL

Comment: Should I include AC coupling capacitors on the RD+/- pair, even though the reference schematic does not include them?

Answer (score 1):

Is this the data sheet you mean http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snls339b/snls339b.pdf
It's the only one I found on the DP83620. Maybe you have an earlier revision? If this is the data sheet then maybe it's the diagram on page 41? Table 2.4.8 says the TD+/- pins need 3.3V bias for correct operation in 100BASE-FX mode - maybe this is the answer? It does show 50R pull-up directly on the outputs on the page 41 diagram too. They are also impied in the diagram on the page before by virtue that they couple to a transformer whose centre pin is at Vdd (presumably +3.3V)